# Permission not recognized by collaboration sub-site

Tags: security

I created a sub-site and disinherited from parent. This sub-site contains two specific permission groups. However, people outside the permission groups can still access the site, albeit with read only capability. The site has no anonymous access too. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Did you delete the users from the site collection? They may not show access, but if you delete them from the site collection they will not have rights anywhere on the site...

Answer (score 1):

Does either of the permission groups have all authenticated users part of it?  Is this using any of the publishing infrastructure?  One of the groups (style resource readers) is open to all authenticated users.

Are there any policies in place in Central Admin that would be opening this up to all users?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I will investigate this areas you mentioned before replying back.. thanks again :)